# jQuery reset css on active button when another button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to style a group of buttons with jQuery. For the active button I want it to look different, so the user knows its active.

These buttons are being generated with a php foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($result as $row){
  echo "<a class='linkClass linkStyle' onclick='javascript:swapContent(" . $row['Count'] . "," . $row['ProductID'] . ");'>" . $row['Count'] . "</a>";
}
```

and i'm trying to style it with this jQuery click function:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('.linkClass').eq(0).click(); })

$(".linkStyle").click(function() {       
   $(this).css("background","#258ace");
   $(this).css("border-top-color", "#258ace");
 });
```

The first bit clicks the first button so that when users come to the page they know what active content is being displayed. My problem is that when another button is pressed the styles are applied to it and they remain on the other button as well. I need a way to reset or remove the class of linkStyles when another button is pressed and only apply it to whatever button is active at the time.

Comment: It's far easier to add and remove a class than a set of css styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript:

```
$(".linkStyle").click(function() {    
   $('.linkStyle.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');   
 });
```

CSS:

```
.linkStyle.active{
background:#258ace;
border-top-color:#258ace;
}
```

PHP:

```
$active=" active";
foreach($result as $row){
  echo "<a class='linkClass linkStyle".$active."' onclick='javascript:swapContent(" . $row['Count'] . "," . $row['ProductID'] . ");'>" . $row['Count'] . "</a>";
  $active="";
}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but lacks the morale of the story: "It is always better to use classes, not edit the css on the node for many reasons: reusability, maintainability, tier separation, etc"

Comment: This has the added benefit that the first row is styled even before the entire document is loaded and ready.

Comment: @LexPodgorny Yes, I will rarely, if ever, apply styles directly to HTML, instead choosing to apply classes that can then be used for styling.  This is especially important when you might want to change the styles later, or if you allow users to have differing styles, or if you want to do responsive designs in which the style may change based on the device or (the current) size of the browser.

Comment: It's also far easier to override for different situations due to specificity.

Answer (score 1):

you can always call:

```
$("#clicked-button-selector").addClass('active-css-class-name');
```

on the button clicked and then remove the style of the first button by calling:

```
$("#first-button-selector").removeClass('active-css-class-name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first resetting all styles of all buttons affected and then apply your css.
It could be:

```
$(".linkStyle").click(function() {       
   resetBtnStyles();
   $(this).css("background","#258ace");
   $(this).css("border-top-color", "#258ace");
});
```

I know it is dirty but it works...